# Django post list json

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send a list in JSON with more parameters. All the parameters works but not the list, which is saved as an empty list. I'm using Django REST Framework and a nested serializer.

This is my `serializers.py`

```
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ('tagID', 'tagName')

class IncentiveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags=TagSerializer(many=True,read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Incentive
        fields = ('schemeName', 'schemeID','text','typeID','typeName','status','ordinal','tags','modeID',
        'groupIncentive','condition')
```

This is my `models.py`

```
class Incentive(models.Model):
    highlighted = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ... more fields ....
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    #email = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Use the `pygments` library to create a highlighted HTML
        representation of the code snippet.
        """
        lexer = get_lexer_by_name(self.language)
        options = self.schemeName and {'title': self.schemeName} or {}
        formatter = HtmlFormatter(text=self.text,
                              full=True, **options)
        self.highlighted = highlight(self.schemeName, lexer, formatter)
        super(Incentive, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


class Tag(models.Model):
    incentiveID = models.ForeignKey(Incentive,related_name="tags")
    tagID= models.IntegerField()
    tagName = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('incentiveID', 'tagID')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Tag, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return '%d: %s' % (self.tagID, self.tagName)
```

I am sending in this information as JSON

```
{
    "schemeName": "SendEmails", 
    "schemeID": 1234, 
    "text": "HelloWorld", 
    "typeID": 345, 
    "typeName": "Emails", 
    "status": true, 
    "ordinal": 0, 
    "tags": [{"tagID":123,"tagName":"dor"}], 
    "modeID": 0, 
    "groupIncentive": false, 
    "condition": "SendEmails"
}
```

And the result I am getting back from the server is

```
{
    "schemeName": "SendEmails", 
    "schemeID": 1234, 
    "text": "HelloWorld", 
    "typeID": 345, 
    "typeName": "Emails", 
    "status": true, 
    "ordinal": 0, 
    "tags": [], 
    "modeID": 0, 
    "groupIncentive": false, 
    "condition": "SendEmails"
}
```

How can I make it save the tags as a list?

Comment: Maybe in your post request content type is not correct you need to set content type application/json

Comment: it's application/json i'm doing it from the api of json-rest-framework all the other fields are OK

Answer (score 1):

Django REST Framework is ignoring the `tags` that are being sent in being the `tags` field on the `IncentiveSerializer` is set to `read_only=True`, which means that tags cannot be added, they are only able to be read. Because of this, all of the tags are being ignored and nothing is hitting the database.

You can fix this by setting `read_only=False` instead, but this will require you to override `create` and `update` on the serializer, and DRF 3 does not handle nested serializers by default. The Django REST Framework documentation has [some useful information](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) for implementing these methods in a generic way, but it will most likely be specific to the serializer.

```
class IncentiveSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags=TagSerializer(many=True,  read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Incentive
        fields = ('schemeName', 'schemeID','text','typeID','typeName','status','ordinal','tags','modeID',
        'groupIncentive','condition')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        tags_data = validated_data.pop("tags", [])

        # Ignores tags without a tagId
        tags_ids = [tag["tagId"] for tag in tags_data if "tagId" in tag]

        incentive = super(IncentiveSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

        if tags_ids:
            tags = Tag.objects.filter(tagId__in=tags_ids)
            incentive.tags.add(*tags)

        return incentive
```

This should allow you to add the `tags` when creating the `Incentive`, but it requires that the tag already exists and can be found by the `tagId`. You may need to change this to meet what you are looking for, as the creation and updating of nested objects is *very* situation dependent.

Comment: I need to remove the foreignkey from Tag?
If i want to create the tags if they doesn't exists how should i do it? Thanks!

Comment: this: `tags_data = validated_data.pop("tags",[])` is always coming empty

Comment: Keep the foreign key on `Tag`, set `read_only=False` on the `tags` field on your serializer

Comment: i copied your code and i print into a file 'tag_data' and i always [{}] like this, do you know why?